# how to put image and texts on img html css

Tags: html, css

I have image and I should make picture and place text also text on button it like in this picture, I want to put text in yellow button also substitute all text

All texts should be like

HTML :

```
<div style="width: 450px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
    <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- ^Текст --> <span style="display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 390px; height: 400px; margin-left:10px">
                                        <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dbaQzUC.png" alt="" style="width: 250px" class="fluid-img">  <a href="http://icome.su">Подробнее</a></div>



                                </span>

                <!-- $Текст -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.image-wrapper { position: relative; }
 .image-wrapper a { position: absolute; left: 235; top: 340; padding: 10px; 
  color: black; margin: 5px; }

  .image-wrapper2  a { position: absolute;left: 235; top: 340; padding: 10px; 
  color: black; margin: 5px;}
.fluid-img {
        height:auto !important;
        max-width:870px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 90% !important;
    }
    .fluid-img2{
        height:auto !important;
        max-width:800px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-top:-100px
    }
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ouxmLz/#&togetherjs=MSLDGq8LI3)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your image (without the exact dimensions). Check it out :

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container .discount,
.img-container .desc,
.img-container img,
.img-container p,
.img-container span,
.img-container a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.img-container .discount {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
}
.img-container .discount span {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img-container .desc {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}
.img-container .desc a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
 <div class="discount">
  <span>50%</span>
 </div>
 <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/250/350/2" alt="" />
 <div class="desc">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam natus minus corporis exercitationem.</p>
  <a href="">Enter</a>>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but why your code also not working in email html

Comment: Emails are very specifics, it's not like usual webpages and we have to use tables instead of standard divs. You need to send this by email ?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EgLKV/3/

Its done by using position:absolute and z-index to place the text over the image.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="image.jpg"/>
    <p id="text">
    <a href="#" i="button">Visit</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#container
{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
}

#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#text
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:150px;
    top:350px;
}

#button
{
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: @Sultan: Your code in the question works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Alternative text" />
    <p class="discount">50%</p>
    <p class="desc">This is a description text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.discount {
    background: #EE6666;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 75px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.desc {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/essdz3do/)

Comment: thanks but I have tried your code it works in browser but I cannot make it work in email html???